# How to deal with way too long STL template error report?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

When programming in c++ STL, or intensively using 'templatization', and some compiling error happens, often the error report is really long, and often too much not needed information is given. 
I'm talking about gcc, i don't know if with other compilers is different, but some times even for just a typo, it takes a while to catch the error purging the

```
<ns::type<ns::type<ns::type, ns::type<...><ns::type<...> > > > >
```

I'm looking for some compiler flag, trick, workaround or methodology ( i currently copy past the error  and put on two lines what i have and what compiler use to want and removing variables bookmarks... (kinda sad procedure for a not-so-uncommon ctrl+s non well performed)) that could make this task quicker or just helping me ( even only some IDE error syntax highlight... )

Comment: Compiling with another compiler is often very, very useful.  gcc, Visual C++, EDG-based compilers (like Comeau or Intel C++), and Clang all produce very different diagnostic messages for template compilation errors.  All of them have some diagnostic messages that are very useful, and all of them have some that are completely useless.  If you compile with more than one compiler, there's a far better chance that you'll get a more useful diagnostic message.

Comment: uhm, i'll try that. I thought they were pretty standard, however it's not very comfortable.

Comment: got fed up with this as well and built this: https://mqnc.github.io/cpptypeexplorer/
it collapses all type info (but it crashes on relation signs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[STLFilt: An STL Error Message Decryptor for C++](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) is a popular tool to filter these verbose error messages and turn them into something more legible.

From their website:

> STLFilt was initially conceived as a teaching aid, to allow students
>   taking C++ and/or STL-specific workshops to make sense of typically
>   overbloated STL error messages. Today, however, even some C++ experts
>   have adopted STLFilt for use in everyday development. The results may
>   not always be perfect, but most of the time the information lost
>   during Decryption is not critical to the application being debugged.
>   The rest of the time, Decryption is easy enough to bypass.
>
> The distribution for each platform (compiler/library set) is
>   self-contained and tuned to the idiosyncrasies of that platform. Each
>   Perl script performs basic regex substitutions for all the standard
>   (and extended, if present in the library) STL components, while
>   certain versions of the script go further with respect to message
>   ordering, line wrapping, library header error treatment, etc., as I
>   unilaterally deemed appropriate for that platform.

Here's [a demo run](http://www.bdsoft.com/dist/gcc-demo.txt) that shows how it can be useful:

> The source program:
>
> ```
> #include <map>
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <cmath>
>
> const int values[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
> const int NVALS = sizeof values / sizeof (int);
>
> int main()
> {
>     using namespace std;
>
>     typedef map<int, double> valmap;
>
>     valmap m;
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < NVALS; i++)
>         m.insert(make_pair(values[i], pow(values[i], .5)));
>
>     valmap::iterator it = 100;              // error
>     valmap::iterator it2(100);              // error
>     m.insert(1,2);                          // error
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> First, an unfiltered run using the MinGW gcc 3.2 compiler:
>
> ```
> d:\src\cl\demo>c++2 rtmap.cpp
> rtmap.cpp: In function `int main()':
> rtmap.cpp:19: invalid conversion from `int' to `
>    std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, double> >*'
> rtmap.cpp:19:   initializing argument 1 of `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val, _Ref,
>    _Ptr>::_Rb_tree_iterator(std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>*) [with _Val =
>    std::pair<const int, double>, _Ref = std::pair<const int, double>&, _Ptr =
>    std::pair<const int, double>*]'
> rtmap.cpp:20: invalid conversion from `int' to `
>    std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, double> >*'
> rtmap.cpp:20:   initializing argument 1 of `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val, _Ref,
>    _Ptr>::_Rb_tree_iterator(std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>*) [with _Val =
>    std::pair<const int, double>, _Ref = std::pair<const int, double>&, _Ptr =
>    std::pair<const int, double>*]'
> E:/GCC3/include/c++/3.2/bits/stl_tree.h: In member function `void
>    std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert_unique(_II,
>
>    _II) [with _InputIterator = int, _Key = int, _Val = std::pair<const int,
>    double>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, double> >,
>    _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int,
>    double> >]':
> E:/GCC3/include/c++/3.2/bits/stl_map.h:272:   instantiated from `void std::map<_
> Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _Input
> Iterator = int, _Key = int, _Tp = double, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = st
> d::allocator<std::pair<const int, double> >]'
> rtmap.cpp:21:   instantiated from here
> E:/GCC3/include/c++/3.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1161: invalid type argument of `unary *
>    '
> ```
>
> And a filtered run using the gcc-specific Proxy c++:
>
> ```
> d:\src\cl\demo>c++ rtmap.cpp
>   *** {BD Software Proxy c++ for gcc v3.01} STL Message Decryption is ON! ***
> rtmap.cpp: In function `int main()':
> rtmap.cpp:19: invalid conversion from `int' to `iter'
> rtmap.cpp:19:   initializing argument 1 of `iter(iter)'
> rtmap.cpp:20: invalid conversion from `int' to `iter'
> rtmap.cpp:20:   initializing argument 1 of `iter(iter)'
> stl_tree.h: In member function `void map<int,double>::insert_unique(_II, _II)':
>     [STL Decryptor: Suppressed 1 more STL standard header message]
> rtmap.cpp:21:   instantiated from here
> stl_tree.h:1161: invalid type argument of `unary *'
>
> STL Decryptor reminder:
>     Use the /hdr:L option to see all suppressed standard lib headers
> ```
>
> [Note: demo runs were performed in an 80-column console window with
>   STLFilt's intelligent line wrapping enabled, and with internal
>   switches set to produce messages as terse as possible. More detail is
>   available by tailoring the Decryptor's options.]

<sup>The only downside I can see is that it mislabels the **C++ Standard Library**. :(</sup>

Here's [a relevant journal article](http://web.archive.org/web/20041012175848/www.cuj.com/documents/s=8024/cuj0107zolman/) by STLFilt's author.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Kev: Perhaps, though, downvotes should be reserved for incorrect information, not "ill-presented" information. EDIT: Also, that analogy doesn't even hold for this particular Q&A.

Comment: @GMan - I didn't even see the vote spread when I reviewed the flag. However, answers that are just a link are discouraged, we like to see them backed up with a summary of what users are likely to expect to see at the other end. It also adds more grist to the search engine results mill.

Comment: @Kev: I'm not arguing that it's not preferable to have a summary, just that people shouldn't be downvoting for it.

Comment: @Kev: I know. I usually spread that point with a vengeance. But I really can't be bothered today. And, really, in this case the link _is_ the answer because the question isn't terribly constructive.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly hat i was looking for. I knew there must be something. I just didn't figure it out to call it _decrypter_ :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - that's a way better answer now, thanks for sorting :)

Comment: @Kev: No worries. I wish you'd jump like this on all the terrible non-answers that _I_ flag! ;)

Comment: For unknown reason nowhere is an explanation how to use the script without compiler — one obviously don't want to recompile a project with the filter if an error is present. So, here it is: the `STLfilt` have a script in perl to filter the output, to name it is `gSTLFilt.pl`. It takes an error list from input, and throw result to output; so one could just save an error to a file «errlog», and use a command `cat errlog | perl gSTLFilt.pl`

Answer (score 4):

A few people have made tools to perform this, as there's nothing inbuilt. Tonnes on Google, but the top result returns: http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html

It should be compatible with visual studio and gcc.

edit::

I need to type less to actually get input in time :)